# Mailgun to Gmail and reply

Tags: email, gmail, mailgun

I have a website example.com and I want my customers to be able to send emails to `support@example.com`. I am used to using Gmail so I would like to receive all emails to my gmail account: `me@gmail.com` and reply to my customers using the Gmail interface.

I am trying to use Mailgun and Amazon's Route 53 to make this all happen. In one direction I would like to make this work:

> some_customer@yahoo.com  --> support@example.com  --> Mailgun  --> (transforms the sender address "some_customer@yahoo.com" to some "middleman@mailgun.com") --> me@gmail.com

In other words, when the customer sends `support@example.com` an email, it reaches my Gmail inbox.

In the other direction, when I am replying to my customer using my Gmail web interface that I am familiar with:

> me@gmail.com  --> middleman@mailgun.com  --> Mailgun  --> (transforms the sender address "me@gmail.com" to "support@example.com")  --> some_customer@yahoo.com

In the second step, since I want to reply to the customer, I just reply to `middleman@mailgun.com` and Mailgun will simply change my gmail address to `support@example.com` before forwarding it to my customer.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better way is to just let Gmail do the receiving by putting MX records in Route53 that points to Google's mail servers.

For the sending, put in a TXT record that lets both Gmail and Mailgun send out emails on behalf of your domain:

```
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:mailgun.org ~all"
```

Also you may want to enable DKIM for signing your emails.

Comment: Hi,have a pointer about corresponding MX configuration in Route53 ?

Comment: This is probably impossible.

Comment: hey can you explain a bit...how did it work. Some steps. I am using mandrill and completely lost how is getting some json at webhook a step forward..what am i expected to make custom email client

Comment: do you have to have gmail apps business account